# Use lookup to auto suggest

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column

I have a list containing 200 items (List A)

In my new list (List B) I want to include a lookup that will pull through the title from List A. OOTB lookup columns are drop downs and as List A continues to grow this isn't going to be fit for purpose so what I want to do have a single line of text that will work like googles search bar and once the user begins typing the title of an Item in List A it will show suggestions.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this without complex coding